# how to solve 404 Not found in tomcat7 server?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat7, cpanel

My spring-hibernate project working perfect in my local PC but when i am deploying .jsp files are running fine but controller are not running. 
Its gives 404 Not found error.

And my another project will run perfect on server.
same directory structure of both project.

```
  [live server directory structure : /home/fugen/public_html/myproject]
```

What are the issues? i have spent two days,but still i am facing.
Thank to all in advance.

my project is on cPanel.

Comment: FAIL - Application at context path /myproject could not be started in fugen.com/manager/html in tomcat web application manager. Now any idea ? how to resolve

Answer (score 0):

Put your jsp file on WEB-INF directory and where you refer this directory refer its directly by jsp file name.

```
filePath="fileName.jsp"
```

But if your file in under any directory of WEB-INF put its full path, e.g. `WEB-INF/jsp/filename.jsp`

Comment: jsp files working perfect. but from jsp file controller is not call. and same structure other project is working fine. #piyush Ghediya

Comment: before calling controller just use context path before it. same like this  <c:set var="context" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
<script src="${context}/themes/js/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: I have tried as you said still i am facing same problem. @Piyush

Comment: Now its done. version issue is there. live server is on JDK 7 and in my local i am using JDK8.. so its compile issue. so i have change Java Compiler from Right click on Project -> Java Compiler -> and select 1.7 from drop down of right panel. and its done. Thank you